# Send mail to Users after activation by Admin in joomla 3.x

Tags: php, joomla

Joomla's default behavior says: *It automatically sends users an email after the administrator has activated their accounts*. But it doesn't work.
Now I want to add this feature. How to do it? Could not find a proper plugin for that. So I'm thinking about editing the core file.

Comment: You should probably give more information about your setup. Especially what mail server is used and how is it configured. A mail server is usually configured in the hosting config panel, not as a part of Joomla, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct - Joomla will always attempt to send an email to an activated user (you can see this in the `activate` function in the `components/com_users/models/registration.php` core Joomla file). However, the email may not reach the user if one of the following is true:

- The email settings in the Joomla configuration are incorrect. Typically, PHP Mailer is the right setting.
- The email is being sent from an IP that is not allowed to send emails on behalf of the domain (this is an SPF issue, which we discussed on our blog [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/spf-records-and-sending-emails-from-your-joomla-website)). Make sure that the server IP is in the SPF list for the domain and also make sure that the "From Email" is an email on that very domain.
- There are some firewall rules on the server itself blocking emails from being sent.

Your host can typically help you (but is not obliged to) with addressing any of the above 3 issues.